# Convert wave files to hex files for programming flash memory chip

Tags: hex, wav, waveform, wave, hexagonal-tiles

I need to convert some PCM wave files to HEX files so I can program my memory chip. What is the proper way of doing it?

I couldn't find a utility that simply does the conversion. I know some software like [hexedit](http://www.catch22.net/software/hexedit) can edit the files in hex format, but how do I convert the files to programmable hex format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is your friend...

Try searching "bin2hex" or "bin2asm" or "bin2c"

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know bin2hex, but I am not quite sure if the "bin" here includes the wave files, or it means something else? and the hex I get will be able to be programmed into the flash memory chip? Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: You may have to write your own converter, or one may have come with your embedded compiler\assembler.
WAVe files **are** just binary files so you may just be able to include those. But WAVe files also have headers and footers describing the audio format of that particular file, and these may need to be stripped away, or replaced a header specific to the embedded chip.
Basically you need to go back to your embedded chip documentation and find out what format is needed and proceed from there.